# How do I validate a group of checkboxes with YUI3 AlloyUI?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3, alloy-ui

I have a form field with a group of checkboxes and at least one of the many checkboxes must be selected in order to submit the form.

**How do I use YUI3 rules to make this happen?**

Many thanks,
S

```
rules: {
    fname: {
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    tel: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
    },
    dob: {
        date: true,
    },
},
fieldContainer: '.form__item',
containerErrorClass: 'form__item--error',
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="form__item form__item--group">
    <legend class="form__item__label">
        A group of checkboxes
        <div class="form__item__label__instructions">
            Select one of them.
        </div>
    </legend>

    <input name='errorMessageAnchor' hidden/>

    <label class="form__item__label" for="cb1">
        <input id="cb1" name="cbName" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /> One
    </label>
    <label class="form__item__label" for="cb2">
        <input id="cb2" name="cbName" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /> Two
    </label>
    <label class="form__item__label" for="cb3">
        <input id="cb3" name="cbName" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /> Three
    </label>
    <label class="form__item__label" for="cb4">
        <input id="cb4" name="cbName" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /> Four
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Does it have to be using `rules` or are you asking how to validate a checkbox group in general?

Comment: I am using AlloyUI YUI3 *'aui-form-validator'* script to validate my form. I want to use the script or extend the scripts rules in order to make at least one of the checkboxes in a particular form field required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source for aui-form-validator](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/master/src/aui-form-validator/js/aui-form-validator.js), the [use of mix](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/yui-mix.html) indicates how to approach a solution.

For simplicity, I've also included a usage of `gallery-checkboxgroups`, specifically for [CheckboxGroup](http://jafl.github.io/yui-modules/yuidoc/classes/CheckboxGroup.html) to have access to `allUnchecked` function.

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
 <div class="control-group">

    <div>
        <h5>Checkbox Group (requries at least 1 selection)</h5>

        Checkbox 1<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='cbName'/><br/> 
        Checkbox 2<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='cbName'/><br/>
        Checkbox 3<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='cbName'/> 
    </div>
</div>
<input class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

**JS**

```
YUI().use('aui-form-validator', 
          'gallery-checkboxgroups',
           function(Y) {

             var group = new Y.CheckboxGroup(Y.all('.checkbox'))

             var CONFIG = Y.config.FormValidator;
             Y.mix(CONFIG.RULES, {atLeastOneCheckbox: function(val, fieldNode, ruleValue) {
                    return !group.allUnchecked()
                }});

             var validator = new Y.FormValidator(
                    {
                        boundingBox: '#myForm',
                        rules: {
                            cbName:{custom:true, atLeastOneCheckbox:true}
                        }
                    }
            );

        }
);
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/0yak4z07/)

---

To override the default error message

```
 Y.mix(CONFIG.STRINGS,{atLeastOneCheckbox:"Pick at least 1"});
```

By default the form validator is going to validate `onBlur` and since all the checkboxes share the same `name`, the error message will move around respectively to the last "failed" validation field. To address this issue, place a hidden field `<input name='errorMessageAnchor' hidden/>` above the group, and associate the error with that field by replacing `cbName` in the rules

```
errorMessageAnchor:{custom:true, atLeastOneCheckbox:true}
```

Comment: This is excellent, many thanks. I am having issues placing the error message where i want though. I will add the HTML I am working with.

Comment: I am hoping to get the error to appear at the bottom of my form field in the plugins error container  `stackErrorContainer: '<div class="form__item__field__message"></div>',`

Comment: You should be able to put the hidden input within the `div`.

Comment: The error container **div** is generated by the plugin